# MGSplitViewController as Modal not working correctly

Tags: objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

I am trying to use an MGSplitViewController, but rather than having it set as the rootViewController, I want it to show modally.  This is the code I am using so far

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if(splitViewController == nil)
    {
        self.splitViewController = [[MGSplitViewController alloc] init];
        self.rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
        self.detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
    }


    [splitViewController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:rootViewController, detailViewController, nil]];

    if (NO) { // whether to allow dragging the divider to move the split.
        splitViewController.splitWidth = 15.0; // make it wide enough to actually drag!
        splitViewController.allowsDraggingDivider = YES;
    }

    splitViewController.delegate = detailViewController;

    [rootViewController performSelector:@selector(selectFirstRow) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
    [detailViewController performSelector:@selector(configureView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];

    [self presentViewController:splitViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

This works almost fine, but the buttons in the detailViewController do not work.  They do nothing.  Also, when I click a button in the left panel, the text doesn't change in the detailViewController as it does in the same project.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can anyone shed any light on this? I think it might have something to do with the delegate. I put an NSLog command in the splitViewController toggleMasterView method,but that is not getting called when I click the Toggle Master button. The toggleMasterView method in the detailViewController IS getting called. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm also working with MGSplitViewController, but it sounds to me like you need to set up some communication between your master and detail views. If you look at the demo project, you can see they use delegates to that effect.